# What is instance URL has to be entered in app?

Tags: android, url, orangehrm

I want to use `Orange HRM` in the app also. while opening the app it is asking me to enter the Instance URL. However, I don't have an idea about What is instance `URL` and what to enter there?  Could anyone pls explain my query.
I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

App only works for paid version   They Forgot to tell anyone and they don't seem to answer anyone's Questions.